# Trying to Add to Database: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute?

Tags: c#

Below is my controller That I am calling from a href button and passing an id. The href button is a duplicate button which is meant to create a copy of the selected module and add it to the database and then return it.

```
   public ActionResult dupe(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        MODULE Modules = db.MODULE.Find(id);
        if (Modules == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

         else
        {
            MODULE newMOd = new MODULE();

            newMOd.APPLY__FINISH = Modules.APPLY__FINISH;

            newMOd.CREATED_BY = Modules.CREATED_BY;   

            newMOd.CREATED_DATE = Modules.CREATED_DATE;

            newMOd.MODULE_DESC = "Duplicate-"+Modules.MODULE_DESC;

            newMOd.MODULE_TYPE = Modules.MODULE_TYPE;

            newMOd.MODULE_TYPE1 = Modules.MODULE_TYPE1;

            newMOd.PRODUCT_LINE = Modules.PRODUCT_LINE;
            newMOd.MODULE_NAME = "Duplicate-" + Modules.MODULE_NAME;

            foreach (MODULE_PARTS mp in Modules.MODULE_PARTS)
            {
                newMOd.MODULE_PARTS.Add(mp);
            }
            foreach (MODULE_OPTION mo in Modules.MODULE_OPTION)
            {
                MODULE_OPTION m = new MODULE_OPTION();
                m.OPTION_NAME = mo.OPTION_NAME;
                m.OPTION_TYPE = mo.OPTION_TYPE;
                m.PRODUCT_LINE = mo.PRODUCT_LINE;
                m.ADDED_BY = mo.ADDED_BY;
                m.ADDED_ON = mo.ADDED_ON;
                m.DEFAULT_FACTOR = mo.DEFAULT_FACTOR;
                foreach (OPTION_PARTS op in mo.OPTION_PARTS)
                {

                    m.OPTION_PARTS.Add(op);

                }
                newMOd.MODULE_OPTION.Add(mo);
            }
            newMOd.MODULE_PARTS = Modules.MODULE_PARTS;
            newMOd.MODULE_OPTION = Modules.MODULE_OPTION;
            db.MODULE.Add(newMOd);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        return View(Modules);
    }
```

This is my controller method, and when I try to add this module to database I get collection modified error. I'm not sure how or where?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3qdU.png)

Comment: Which **exact** line of code throws the error.

Comment: db.MODULE.Add(newMOd);

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the IDE showing that exception occurring? I am surprised that is where the exception is occurring.

Comment: added, also while debugging i noticed my module id is 0, could this be why?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] so we could see what `db` is and `db.MODULE` is.

Answer (score -1):

The exception message in this case is quite clear... you cannot modify a member of a collection you are currently iterating over. It's that simple.

Comment: im not iterating over anything tho

Comment: @BrennanPrasad foreach is not iterating over a collection?